# Keycloak angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, keycloak

I have a project microservices springboot. I secure the backend using keycloak with option secret credentials and auth2.

I test with a postman it's work well. But when I build a project ui with angular I c'ant access to app an error 401 unauthorized.
I need to know how can I configure angular to access the backend?

Answer (score 0):

Use the client that is configured in the Postman and use this site guide to add to your angular project [How to use angular-oauth2-oidc](https://synk.io/advisor/npm-package/angular-oauth2-oidc/example)